# Add icon next to filename

Tags: php, html

I have the following code which sorts files in its current directory:

```
<?php
$folders = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');

foreach ($folders as $foldlist) {

echo "<tr><td><img src=\"/index/RESSOURCES/icon/folder.png\"></td><td><a href=\"{$foldlist}\">{$foldlist}</a></td><td><a href=\"#info\" onclick=\"loadDoc('{$foldlist}')\"><img src=\"/RESSOURCES/icon/info.png\"></a></td></tr>";
}
$files = glob("*.*");

foreach ($files as $filename) {
$type=substr($filename,strrpos($filename,'.')+1);
echo "<tr><td><img src=\"/index/RESSOURCES/icon/{$type}.png\"></td><td><a href=\"{$filename}\">{$filename}</a></td><td><a href=\"#info\" onclick=\"loadDoc('{$filename}')\"><img src=\"/RESSOURCES/icon/info.png\"></a></td></tr>";
}

?>
```

It works, don't worry about that. There is only a minor problem that I've been troubleshooting for the last few days:

If you run my code, you'll see that before every file name, there is an icon. It fetches the right icon by taking the file s format. Cool, right?

But here is my problem:
Lets say I have two files: dummy.zip and dummy.tar.

Both files will fetch "zip.png" and "tar.png" - The two icons are exactly the same. So basically, im making the client load two times the same icon, witch makes my page significally slower. Nothing dramatic? Well, I have over a hundred files right now... Witch pretty much all of them having a different format.

How can I make it so:
if $icon == zip OR tar OR gz LOAD zip.png?

Cheers.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you are asking. First of all the file extension is no indication of what is inside the file. Even a folder name can contain .png in the name, so your glob could also get you folders. Second of all, there could be thousands of field extensions, and I doubt you have a separate icon for every single one.

Comment: Try something like this. Make a fixed list of the icons you have and store it in associative array. Then when you look on your directory contents check if the extension is in your array, if not then use a generic file icon. This way you can map multiple extensions to a single icon.

Comment: the browser won't load the icon twice, if the path is the same it will use the image from the local cache

Comment: @DavidBray - First I also decided the question is about it, but it's not. The author gets different files with different paths, but some of the files may contain the same icon image and he wants to load only one image in such cases

Comment: yeah you right - he wasn't doing the work to classify the file type

Comment: @Dharman In case you didnt noticed, this piece of code fetches the folders and files separately. So, if a folder is named "foo.txt", it still will have the folder icon. :)

Comment: Have you tried it? Name a folder `foo.txt` and check if `$files = glob("*.*");` will not match that entry.

Comment: @Dharman nope, it doesnt. See screenshot here: https://i.postimg.cc/MZQ1LBSM/snap28244.png

Comment: Well I can clearly see `foo.txt` twice in that list. Once as a file and once as a folder. So unless you have also a file named like this then I am right.

Comment: Oh. Ive done a goof there... You were right.

Comment: I deleted my first glob function that seeked for folders. I now need to find how to do the following: IF theres no extension DO stuff-- But the extension finder I made tells me that the folder s name is "ESSOURCE" (It simply removes the first letter). Any tips?

Comment: Nevermind, I can simply specify "ESSOURCES" as an extension. Lazy, but hey, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your line

```
$type = substr($filename,strrpos($filename,'.')+1);
```

and before

```
echo "<tr><td><img src=\"/index/RESSOURCES/icon/{$type}.png\"></td><td><a href=\"{$filename}\">{$filename}</a></td><td><a href=\"#info\" onclick=\"loadDoc('{$filename}')\"><img src=\"/RESSOURCES/icon/info.png\"></a></td></tr>";
```

you may just add the following code

```
if($type == 'zip' || $type == 'tar' || $type == 'gz') {
    $type = 'zip';
}
```

It will load `zip.png` for all the three cases